# Access elements of a vector in a structure array MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a structure which contains two fields one of them contains vectors,example:

```
myStruct(1).f1 = val1;
myStruct(1).f2 = [elt1 elt2 elt3];
```

I want to find the indices of the elements of `myStruct` where `elt1 == valA` and `elt2 == valB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

```
% Create a matrix whose rows are the f2 vectors in the struct array
A = cell2mat({myStruct.f2}.');

% Find which rows match your conditions
Matches = (A(:,1) == valA) & (A(:,2) == valB);

% (If required: convert logical vector to indices)
Indices = find(Matches);
```

Comment: Thank you! it works without even converting the logical vector to indices

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
F2 = reshape([myStruct.f2],3,[]); 

Indices = find(((F2(1,:) == valA) & (F2(2,:) == valB)));
```